# ActiveRecord 7: using writing and reading roles without ORM model classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm working on an application that uses ActiveRecord for database access, but does not use ORM features such as model classes - queries are all made with literal SQL and calls to `exec_query`.

I'd like to use the [support for multiple databases in ActiveRecord](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html) in order to selectively opt in to using a read-only connection to a database, but have not been able to work out how to get this working in an application that does not use model classes.

With a model class (from the documentation), I could make a declaration such as:

```
class MyBaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true

    connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :primary_replica }
end
```

and then manually switch into a reading context using e.g.:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) do
    SomeChildModel.find id
end
```

Is there a way of declaring a database connection to use for a reading role (in addition to the default one used for writing), and then being able to elect to use that role in a particular context (making `exec_query` calls on a connection object) so that ActiveRecord is able to manage the connection pool correctly in the background when switching in and out of contexts, as it can with configured model classes as above?

Comment: I wonder why you are using ActiveRecord but not it’s ORM layer?

Comment: It's just how the existing application is set up. It could use pg directly or whatever but it uses ActiveRecord for managing the connections.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question includes your answer. You can just execute code inside the block:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) do
  # all code in this block will be connected to the reading role
end
```

There's nothing that requires code in that block to reference a class or model.

And [more from the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#using-manual-connection-switching):

> There are some cases where you may want your application to connect to a writer or a replica and the automatic connection switching isn't adequate. For example, you may know that for a particular request you always want to send the request to a replica, even when you are in a POST request path.
>
> To do this Rails provides a connected_to method that will switch to the connection you need.

All you should need to do is define your additional databases in your `database.yml` file, [according to the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#setting-up-your-application).

Comment: Thanks for this @Chiperific - my issue seems to be that I don't seem to have a way to establish the mapping between roles and databases that one can set up in a model class, i.e. `connects_to(database: { writing: :writing, reading: :reading })`. I've tried just invoking `connects_to` on `ActiveRecord::Base` but to no effect.